# how to disable specific date range in bootstrap daterangepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I want to disable specific date range in bootstrap daterangepicker.

I need to use bootstrap daterangepicker which provides me the option of restricting the specific date range.

Comment: Have you tired `minDate` and `maxDate` from document?

Comment: actually i want it for banner purchase so, its come with any range.

Comment: any range means? u mean dynamic range?

Comment: yes. Suppose in this month 1st user already purchase for date 3 to 6,2nd user already purchase for date 8 to 10, then this 2 range is disabled in selection.

Comment: so more than one ranges will be disabled?

Comment: @CerlinBoss yes sir...

Comment: Is that may be helpful, more than asked,  here? [One of my recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40638269/2159528)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette : not sure if bootstrap daterangepicker gives a callback option to disable dates like how jquery datepicker does.

Comment: @CerlinBoss yes you are right. I already try this. but Its not working with daterange picker.

Comment: mmm... I just linked a similar question... Answer, lol. It is jQuery-ui. Bootstrap logic, sure is quite similar depending on what is the **day** selection to act on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable dates, use [`datesDisabled` method](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled) to provide an array.

Some dates are disabled in [**this CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PbWpZQ).

```
$("#picker").datepicker({
    datesDisabled:["11/24/2016","11/28/2016","12/02/2016","12/23/2016"]
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Previous answer was for Bootstap DatePicker...
Sorry for the misreading, my bad.

Here is what I have found for Bootstrap DateRangePicker:

```
// Define the disabled date array
var disabledArr = ["11/24/2016","11/28/2016","12/02/2016","12/23/2016"];

$("#picker").daterangepicker({

     isInvalidDate: function(arg){
         console.log(arg);

         // Prepare the date comparision
         var thisMonth = arg._d.getMonth()+1;   // Months are 0 based
         if (thisMonth<10){
             thisMonth = "0"+thisMonth; // Leading 0
         }
         var thisDate = arg._d.getDate();
         if (thisDate<10){
             thisDate = "0"+thisDate; // Leading 0
         }
         var thisYear = arg._d.getYear()+1900;   // Years are 1900 based

         var thisCompare = thisMonth +"/"+ thisDate +"/"+ thisYear;
         console.log(thisCompare);

         if($.inArray(thisCompare,disabledArr)!=-1){
             console.log("      ^--------- DATE FOUND HERE");
             return true;
         }
     }

}).focus();
```

This is working in [**this CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PbWELx?editors=1010).

---

**EDIT for the *bonus question* in comments ;)**

Above, is to *draw* the calendar with disabled dates.
Now, what you need is to compare the selected range again, on ***Apply*** (when user has selected a range), to disallow a range that would include some disabled dates.

So here is an additional function:

```
$("#picker").on("apply.daterangepicker",function(e,picker){

    // Get the selected bound dates.
    var startDate = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    var endDate = picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    console.log(startDate+" to "+endDate);

    // Compare the dates again.
    var clearInput = false;
    for(i=0;i<disabledArr.length;i++){
        if(startDate<disabledArr[i] && endDate>disabledArr[i]){
            console.log("Found a disabled Date in selection!");
            clearInput = true;
        }
    }

    // If a disabled date is in between the bounds, clear the range.
    if(clearInput){

        // To clear selected range (on the calendar).
        var today = new Date();
        $(this).data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(today);
        $(this).data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(today);

        // To clear input field and keep calendar opened.
        $(this).val("").focus();
        console.log("Cleared the input field...");

        // Alert user!
        alert("Your range selection includes disabled dates!");
    }
});
```

See the [**improved CodePen here**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KNWNJg?editors=1010).

Comment: Ha... Sorry for this. But Have you tried [isInvalidDate](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options) ? It looks like to be the same kind of option.

Comment: But still need one more help.
if we disabled date 3 to 5 and some one select from date 1 to 7 then selection is possible here. But i want to disallow it.
Only non disabled date range can select.

Comment: I updated my answer... **Notice** that I corrected a small glitch in the draw function. I changed `return arg._pf = {userInvalidated: true};` for `return true;`... It was causing *moment* errors in console. ;)

Comment: can we add extra class to this disabled date?

Comment: Yes, via CSS, you can manipulate the `disabled` class. To force a propertie which is already defined by Bootstrap, just add `!important` to it. Example : `text-decoration:none !important;` will remove the dash over the date.

Answer (score 3):

Louys Patrice Bessette's answer is awesome.

I just want to make it more accurate because I found 1 bug that it not alert when you choose start date and end date in different month and disabled date in between them. The reason is here

```
startDate<disabledArr[i] && endDate>disabledArr[i]
```

you need to parse to Date Object before comparing or it will be false like this

```
startDate = new Date(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
endDate = new Date(picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'))
```

similar to disabled date in disableArr

**Thank you**

Comment: I just saw your post... Thanks for the precison on my answer. ;) +1